# Array of virtual functions

Tags: c++, class, reverse-engineering

When reverse engineering and using external classes I often try to redefine those classes in my library:

```
class GameEngine // Exported with "GetGameEngine"
{
public:
    virtual void foo1() = 0;
    virtual void foo2() = 0;
    virtual void foo3() = 0;
    virtual void foo4() = 0;
    virtual void foo5() = 0;
    virtual void foo6() = 0;
    virtual void foo7() = 0;
    virtual void foo8() = 0;
    virtual void foo9() = 0;
    virtual void foo10() = 0;
    virtual void foo11() = 0;
    virtual void foo12() = 0;
    virtual int GetGameStatus() = 0; //0x30
    virtual void foo14() = 0;
    virtual void foo15() = 0;
    virtual void foo16() = 0;
    virtual int AnotherUsefulFunction() = 0; //0x40
};
```

Basically I call the GetGameStatus function externally. Is there some structure or a possibility that allows me to write it this like:

```
class GameEngine // Exported with "GetGameEngine"
{
public:
    FUNCTABLE(12);
    virtual int GetGameStatus() = 0; //0x30
    FUNCTABLE(14,16);
    virtual int AnotherUsefulFunction() = 0; //0x40
};
```

It would clean up my code a lot.

Comment: Why do all your functions have these meaningless names?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: I guess this is for reverse engineering, where you want to access someone's else virtual method without having its header file. Knowing the offset of the method you want to call you just need some placeholder calls to fill the space in the class' vtable.

Comment: @liori: Except that the names of the functions would be compiled out and they would be worthless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at [boost::preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html), specifically at its [REPEAT](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) macro. Something like this should work:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/repetition/repeat.hpp>

#define FUNC(fun_z, fun_n, fun_data) virtual void foo ## fun_n () = 0;
#define FUNCTABLE(count) BOOST_PP_REPEAT(count, FUNC, 0)
```